# Why is Tomcat 8.5 reloading context

Tags: java, tomcat8

It seems like since we upgraded tomcat to version 8+ we aways get a context reload on startup.  However it only seems to happen in our development environments (windows OS with eclipse and tomcat 8.5).  Our production environments (linux OS with tomcat 8.5) do not have this issue.  Ill post it below but I do not see any indication of why this is happenign from the tomcat logs.  I know this is normally behavior with something in the web apps directory is changed, but for the life of me i cannot figure out what is doing it.  There must be some way to track it down though.

This first chunk of log is it fully starting

> Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>   WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Stackoverflow-commproxy' did not find a matching property.
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Server built:          Jan 10 2017 21:02:52 UTC
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Server number:         8.5.11.0
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: OS Version:            10.0
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Architecture:          amd64
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b14
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\CodeRepos\work\EclipseWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.11
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\CodeRepos\work\EclipseWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.11
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\CodeRepos\work\EclipseWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\endorsed
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
>   INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Users\dever.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.35.0;C:\Program Files\Emscripten;C:\Program Files\Emscripten\clang\e1.35.0_64bit;C:\Program Files\Emscripten\node\0.12.2_64bit;C:\Program Files\Emscripten\python\2.7.5.3_64bit;C:\Program Files\Emscripten\java\7.45_64bit\bin;C:\Program Files\Emscripten\crunch\1.03;C:\Program Files\Emscripten\mingw\4.6.2_32bit;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\JavaProgramFiles\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\program files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;c:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin;C:\JavaProgramFiles\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin;C:\JavaProgramFiles\xmlbeans-1.0.3\bin;C:\Users\dever\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\dever\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\eclipse\jee-neon\eclipse;;.
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>   INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
>   INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>   INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
>   INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>   INFO: Initialization processed in 610 ms
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
>   INFO: Starting service Catalina
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
>   INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:44 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
>   INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
>   Feb 18, 2017 9:53:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   2017-02-18 09:53:45.755 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.stackoverflow.util.common.AppConfigPostProcessor - Setting system property: org.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j
>   2017-02-18 09:53:45.757 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.stackoverflow.util.common.AppConfigPostProcessor - Setting default timezone to: UTC
>   2017-02-18 09:53:47.990 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.stackoverflow.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
>   2017-02-18 09:53:47.997 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.LoggingServiceImpl - Logging Service: init successfully
>   2017-02-18 09:53:48.011 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: initializing Stackoverflow Device Service...
>   2017-02-18 09:53:48.314 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  com.stackoverflow.cache.mapdb.MapDBCacheManager - Opened StackoverflowCommProxyCacheV4 MapDB store. File location C:\Users\dever\AppData\Local\Temp\StackoverflowCommProxyCacheV4.DeviceMetaDataCache
>   2017-02-18 09:53:48.314 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: loading local DeviceMetaData cache
>   2017-02-18 09:53:48.316 [taskScheduler-1] DEBUG com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: starting device pool refresh task
>   Feb 18, 2017 5:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
>   Feb 18, 2017 5:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
>   Feb 18, 2017 5:53:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   INFO: Server startup in 6928 ms
>   2017-02-18 09:53:49.774 [taskScheduler-1] INFO  com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: received list of device metadata with 15 items from Stackoverflow Cloud Services
>   2017-02-18 09:53:49.775 [taskScheduler-1] DEBUG com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: device metadata cache contains 15 items
>   2017-02-18 09:53:49.806 [taskScheduler-1] INFO  com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: performed refresh cycle. Time spent: 1490 ms
>   Feb 18, 2017 5:53:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
>   INFO: Reloading Context with name [/stackoverflow-commproxy] has started

Notice how there is no error and none of the operations which took place would have touched the disk.  With a slight exception for logging.  Which does log to file however with our settings like this it really shouldnt be touching the web apps directory:

log4j2.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="180">
    <Properties>
        <!-- change the path to conference logs below to fit your system -->
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">C:\CodeRepos\logs\</Property>
```

And the rest of the log file:

> Feb 18, 2017 5:53:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   2017-02-18 09:53:58.514 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: destroying Stackoverflow Device Service...
>   2017-02-18 09:53:58.543 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  com.stackoverflow.cache.mapdb.MapDBCacheManager - Closed StackoverflowCommProxyCacheV4.DeviceMetaDataCache MapDB store
>   2017-02-18 09:53:58.545 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  com.stackoverflow.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
>   Feb 18, 2017 5:53:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
>   WARNING: The web application [Stackoverflow-commproxy] appears to have started a thread named [Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
>    sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
>    java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
>    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
>    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
>    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Feb 18, 2017 5:54:00 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
>   INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
>   Feb 18, 2017 5:54:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
>   Feb 18, 2017 5:54:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   2017-02-18 17:54:01.637 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  com.stackoverflow.util.common.AppConfigPostProcessor - Setting system property: org.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j
>   2017-02-18 17:54:01.639 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  com.stackoverflow.util.common.AppConfigPostProcessor - Setting default timezone to: UTC
>   2017-02-18 17:54:03.732 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  com.stackoverflow.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
>   2017-02-18 17:54:03.739 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.LoggingServiceImpl - Logging Service: init successfully
>   2017-02-18 17:54:03.751 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: initializing Stackoverflow Device Service...
>   2017-02-18 17:54:04.024 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO  com.stackoverflow.cache.mapdb.MapDBCacheManager - Opened StackoverflowCommProxyCacheV4 MapDB store. File location C:\Users\dever\AppData\Local\Temp\StackoverflowCommProxyCacheV4.DeviceMetaDataCache
>   2017-02-18 17:54:04.024 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: loading local DeviceMetaData cache
>   2017-02-18 17:54:04.025 [taskScheduler-1] DEBUG com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: starting device pool refresh task
>   Feb 18, 2017 5:54:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
>   INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Stackoverflow-commproxy] is completed
>   2017-02-18 17:54:04.987 [taskScheduler-1] INFO  com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: received list of device metadata with 15 items from Stackoverflow Cloud Services
>   2017-02-18 17:54:04.987 [taskScheduler-1] DEBUG com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: device metadata cache contains 15 items
>   2017-02-18 17:54:05.020 [taskScheduler-1] INFO  com.stackoverflow.service.commproxy.DeviceServiceImpl - Device Service: performed refresh cycle. Time spent: 995

We can see an error regarding some thread that log4j started and couldnt stop but other than that there is no indication of what caused the context reload, and the error regarding log4j is only happening because of the reload.

How can I track down the cause of context reload.  We have several projects suffering for this issue some it seems something more global than a specific process or class.

**Haven't received any answers so I just wanted to reiterate the fact that Im really looking for my next step in troubleshooting this?  Some other log to look at or some way to find out what is triggering the context reload**

Comment: FYI running tomcat with our war files also does NOT produce the issue

Comment: I know this is not very simple advice but still: you can always build Tomcat from sources and start it under debugger and in the debugger you can place breakpoints on various log messages and trace back the reason from there.

Comment: You should set tomcat internals logging level to ALL, this way you should be able to see which resource caused the reload. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try the following settings:

1. Open your server configuration from Eclipse Servers View

   - then make sure that in this editors Server Options section *"Modules auto reload by default"* is unchecked
   - also make sure that in that editors Publishing section *"Never publish automatically"* is selected
2. Open context menu of your server in Eclipse Servers View

   - select *"Add and Remove..."*
   - in the dialog make sure that *"If server is started, publish changes immediately"* is unchecked and Finish (you might also have to remove all webapps first and add them again in another step)

Comment: Tried, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from current info, so I can just only give some suggestions to help you:

- Checking `conf/context.xml`, you may see whether the your watchedResources is changed.

```html
<!--Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the -->
<!--  web application will be reload.-->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
```

- You may specify the tag in `context.xml` as `<Context reloadable="false">` to try to stop this issue.
- More logging: localhost.date.log, host-manager.date.log
- From [this thread](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26520473/tomcat-standardcontext-reload.html#a33843968), it says it may related with Eclipse and it si suggested to check jars in Eclipse vs the jars used by the installed tomcat:

  > There are sometimes problems when a jar (in Eclispe) has a future timestamp, or is loaded after Tomcat starts, which results in Tomcat reloading the context.
- Implement your `ServletContextListener` and check `ServleConextEvent` to find info about pre context status.

Comment: I have the same problem. The second suggestion works. I still don't understand what is triggering the reload though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **server.xml** file by search with **ctrl+shift+R**
Under  give value as **false** for **reloadable** as follows.

```
<Context docBase="YourAppName" path="/YourApp" reloadable="false" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:YourAppName"/>
```